# Splitting words from a text file

Tags: java, split, delimiter

```
after,before,20 

yes,no,9
```

so i have those words above on a text file and i want to split them to different parts such that i'll get the result:

```
after

before

20
```

and here is my code

```
File files = new File("yes.txt");
Scanner in = new Scanner(files).useDelimiter("\\,"); 

String x = in.next(); 
String y = in.next(); 
String z = in.next(); 

System.out.println(x); 
System.out.println(y); 
System.out.println(z);
```

but the result that comes out is:

```
after

before

20

yes
```

what should i do to remove the "yes"??

Comment: This is a common file-format known as comma-separated values (CSV), and Java most likely has some built-in tools for handling such files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to add the `\n` as a delimeter so that it recognizes newlines. Right now it only recognizes `,` as a delimeter:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(files).useDelimiter(Pattern.compile("[,\\n]"));
```

Answer (score 6):

add one more delimiter, use  `" \\\n "` to filter the newlines